# nvcc/cuda 3.1 - ghtr-default.h flood of "declared static" but not defined warnings

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda, warnings, nvcc

When compiling a project with nvcc (using cuda 3.1), I'm getting a flood of warnings from gthr-default.h:

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:118: warning: ‘int __gthrw_pthread_once(pthread_once_t*, void (*)())’ declared ‘static’ but never defined
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:119: warning: ‘void* __gthrw_pthread_getspecific(pthread_key_t) throw ()’ declared ‘static’ but never defined
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:120: warning: ‘int __gthrw_pthread_setspecific(pthread_key_t, const void*) throw ()’ declared ‘static’ but never defined`

I've dug around all over and can't seem to find a way to suppress this noise, short of removing -Wall, which I don't really want to do.  Does this look familiar to anyone?

My CXXFLAGS are:

```
CXXFLAGS=-Isrc -I../cxxtest -I$(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -Xcompiler -O2 -Xcompiler -Wall
```

I've tried adding the $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) to the -Xcompiler options as well but to no avail.  I don't want to remove Wall from the settings...  are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Try separating your pthreads code into a different file so that you can avoid #including whatever file is triggering those warnings...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any pthreads code - or at least, none specifically #included.  Any threading going on is the result of nvcc doing something behind the scenes...

Comment: Something in your code is pulling in gthr-default.h. Try posting your code. Or just try a more recent version of CUDA e.g. 4.0.