# Why do I get c++ compile warnings depending on header order

Tags: c++, c, gcc, header

I'm using compile flags -Wall -Wextra and -Werror.  I'm getting a flood of "declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Werror=unused-function] " Warnings (treated as errors) when I compile the following file.  No such warnings when I reverse the order of the #include directives.  Please help me understand why?

I know I could remove the extra warnings and errors and get my program to compile, clearly that's not my intent or my code would be more interesting.  I'm trying to gain a deeper knowledge of C++, and improve my habits through cleaning up warnings in my code.

I understand that argp is really a C library, and iostream is a C++ library, perhaps that's part of the issue.  I'd be happy to use a proper C++ library to accomplish what argp does, but I can't find one.  If there is one I'd be happy to hear about it.

```
#include <argp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

To be clear, I am working on a non-trivial program, and have specific reasons for wanting to use C++ instead of C.  I've boiled down the code shown here to the least possible code to produce the effect I'm trying to understand.  Please don't suggest that I don't need one or the other of the headers.

Compiler: gcc

```
    :~/scratch/argp_example$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~12.04) 5.2.1 20151031 Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

compiler invokation:
`g++ -o obj/main.o -c src/main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -MMD --std=c++11 -Iinc`

Specific compiler feedback:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/gthr.h:148:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from src/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/gthr-default.h:101:1: warning: ‘int __gthrw_pthread_once(pthread_once_t*, void (*)())’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Wunused-function] __gthrw(pthread_once) ^
```

There are many many more similar errors from gthr.h.  This specific copy/paste was from a run without -Werror, but that's the only difference.

SOLUTION:
This was my choice of solution, but of course, you could simply reverse the order of includes.  It is a recognized bug, so there is no "correct" answer, all solutions would be workarounds.  This one, I think, is least likely to give me or others fits later.

```
#include <argp.h>
#undef __attributes__
#include <iostream>
...
```

Comment: That is a weird problem.  Perhaps you can confine the parsing to a single module and *not* include iostream in that one?

Comment: Looks to be a GNU bug given this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969419/nvcc-cuda-3-1-ghtr-default-h-flood-of-declared-static-but-not-defined-warnin

Comment: As to substitutes, have you checked [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/program_options.html)?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I did read that, and acknowledge that it's a similar issue, but I don't see where it says on that question that it's a GNU bug.  That question has a lot of specifics to hardware and libraries which are not relevant for my question, so I thought I might be more effective at getting an answer with a more broad question, as there was not enough there for me to understand.

Comment: If you are writing C++ code, use a C++ compiler, like `g++` rather than a C compiler like `gcc`.   Since your writing C++ code, please remove the `c` tag

Comment: @user3629249 gcc is a c++ compiler.  G++ is syntactic sugar. I'll look into whether this bug is c++ specific, but I have no specific reason to believe it's not also a bug in c.

Comment: If you follow the "known bug" link in the accepted answer, you'll see it is a known bug with compiler options --std=cxx (line --std=c89 --std=c90 --std=c99)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16907). The culprit is this chunk of code in `argp.h`, which is triggered when you use `-std=c++xx`:

```
#ifndef __attribute__
/* This feature is available in gcc versions 2.5 and later.  */
# if __GNUC__ < 2 || (__GNUC__ == 2 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5) || __STRICT_ANSI__
#  define __attribute__(Spec) /* empty */
# endif
```

The declarations at issue are normally marked with `__attribute__ ((__weakref__("pthread_meow")))`, but this macro caused that attribute to vaporize.

Until the bug gets fixed, you might want to compile with `-std=gnu++xx`, or manually `#undef __attribute__` after including `argp.h`.

Comment: Could you advise on how best to search for known bugs like this?  Teach a man to fish...?  I wasn't having luck on google.

Comment: @Jfevold Well, I first figured out what's causing it, and then searched whether it's a known issue. Use `g++ -E` to preprocess both versions of the code, check what's different (the `__attribute__ ((__weakref__("...")))` is gone), then check what's causing it (argp.h defining a `__attribute__` macro), then google to see if that's a known issue (it's among the top results for `argp.h __attribute__`.